# SpriteKit Game Centre Force

Tags: ios, sprite, sprite-kit

I'm creating an app and for some reason when I'm running the app on the device and the Welcome to Game Centre drop down appears, the force applied to my SKSpriteNode seems to be greater than normal, making my sprite fly off the screen.

So I add my sprite in the scene in the initWithSize method but then once you click on the screen, the touchesBegan fires which applies a force to the sprite, and if the Game Centre drop down doesn't appear (when you first start up the app) then it will work as per normal. Problem only seems to occur when Game Centre drop down appears.

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: I suppose the issue is simply that due to the GC view the framerate drops, which makes the physics bodies seem to go faster. The best solution is probably to wait for game center authentication before starting the game.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking of doing something similar.